# git create new non-tracking branch based on remote branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch

Situation: open-source project with multiple branches, and my fork of it for contributions.
I want to create a new branch for pull requests on github. I want to base this branch on one of the existing branches on the open-source project, BUT I do NOT want my commits to go into that original branch.

As per my experience, if I clone my fork, execute `git checkout -b my-branch origin/some-branch` and then commit+push to `my-branch`, in Github the commits will go to `some-branch` and not `my-branch`. Obviously, this is problematic if I want to make multiple branches for multiple pull requests on the same branch.

The workaround that I've found for this is the following:

`git checkout -b some-branch origin/some-branch`

`git checkout -b my-branch` (new branch based on some-branch, but not tracking it)

after that - commit+push, first push will create `my-branch` on Github.

However, this leaves me with an extra local copy of `some-branch`. I can delete it later, obviously, but is there a way to avoid creating it at all? Is there a way to create `my-branch`, based on `origin/some-branch`, but not tracking it, in one command, without the extra branch in the middle?

Comment: You may want to post what your push.default is set to as well as your Git version.  Both of these can influence the behavior you are seeing when you push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SHA1 hash of the same commit instead of `origin/some-branch`. Example:

```
git checkout -b my-branch 92fc7a2
```

Remember, a branch is just a label on a commit, nothing more. It's a 41-byte file, containing a SHA1 hash name of a commit and a linefeed.

Comment: Or even `git checkout -b my-branch origin/some-branch^{commit}`

Comment: What commit? I'm asking about branches, not commits...
@jthill - doesn't that just specify a specific entry commit for the tracking branch? I don't want to track that branch at all.

Comment: A branch or a remote branch is just a label on a commit. If you set up a new branch referring to those, tracking is set up. If you refer to the commit directly, the new branch won't track any remote one.

Comment: *"It's a 41-byte file, containing a SHA1 hash name of a commit and a linefeed."* Which is exactly why you should not worry about *"However, this leaves me with an extra local copy of some-branch."*

Comment: @SzG don't actually know :-) edit wait, I think I do -- get yourself on another SE site. I added Programmers for another git question around then.

Comment: Eh, having to look up the hash of the last commit on a branch takes more time than just creating the two branches. Sucks, I think my case is a completely normal use case.